# How to automatically, and non-interactively, get where in the source code a segmentation fault is triggered?

Tags: c, command-line, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am working on an automated testing tool which has found bugs that are usually manifested as segmentation faults. I am trying to find out how many of these detected bugs are unique. Uniqueness is a special term used in my study: If two segmentation faults are triggered by different statements, the two are considered different. My current approach to tell if two segmentation faults are triggered by different statements or not is to use GDB. For example:

```
(gdb) r

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f050c9efac2 in gsl_stats_quantile_from_sorted_data (sorted_data=sorted_data@entry=0x7fffe1477c40, stride=stride@entry=1,
    n=n@entry=5, f=675) at quantiles_source.c:37
37        result = sorted_data[lhs * stride]
```

As you can see, GDB stops at where the segmentation fault arises (line 37 of the C program quantiles_source.c as shown above). I am wondering how to get that piece of information by a command line or script, non-interactively?

Comment: You could run gdb commands from a file with `-x file` or via multiple `-ex command` then exit when done (`--batch`).  You can also enable core dump with `ulimit -c unlimited`, then run gdb over the the core file with similar approach as above to be non-interactive.

Comment: https://www.linutronix.de/minicoredumper might be of interest to you too.

Comment: Also be careful about the information available in the core dump file as it would be possible to the stack frame could have been overwritten

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you for the references. Would you elaborate on that in an answer?

Comment: @zell nothing to add, I am afraid, as I have not used it.  Might be worth reviewing for your use case (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `gdb` non-interactive on the binary by executing the commands specified in file with `-x file`, or you can specify a command with `-ex command` (used multiple times if needed).  In either case when combined with `--batch` it subsequently exit.  Another option configure your shell to allow a core file to dumped with `ulimit -c ulimited` then run `gdb` on the binary and resulting core file using the arguments mentioned above.

Comment: It works with a command like this:  gdb a.out --ex="r < err04" --batch. Thanks!